# Django filter empty fields

Tags: django, orm, django-queryset

Currently I am filtering empty fields in all entries of the queryset like this:

```
data_qs = DataValue.objects.filter(study_id=study.id) #queryset

opts = DataValue._meta  # get meta info from DataValue model
   
field_names = list([field.name for field in opts.fields])  # DataValue fields in a list

field_not_empty = list() # list of empty fields

for field in field_names:
    for entry in data_qs.values(field):
        if entry.get(field) is not None:
            field_not_empty.append(field)
            break
```

It works but not sure if it is an appropriate solution....

Does anyone know how to filter empty values in all the queryset? The table have more than 30 fields, so depending on the study ID some querysets may contain the field1 all empty, other study ID may contain all the field2 empty.

Does the Django ORM provide an easy an clean solution to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain it a little more clearly? What do you mainly want to do, filter the records that have any empty fields??

Comment: Sure. No, if a field contains a value in any of the entries of the queryset should be maintained. If all the entries have an empty value for that field then I want to exclude that field from the queryset. So when I export that queryset to CSV I can save a few columns since will be a an empty column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if some value in a QuerySet is empty, say the values name is "title".

This will exclude all empty fields

```
DataValue.objects.filter(study_id=study.id).exclude(title__exact='')
```

If you only want the empty fields, just filter it

```
DataValue.objects.filter(study_id=study.id, title__exact='')
```

Hope it helped.