# Django How do I check that a choices field is not blank in a filter

Tags: django, django-models

I have a choices field that can be blank

```
   review_comment = models.CharField(max_length=60, choices=REVIEW_COMMENT_CHOICES, blank=True)
```

I now want to filter by review_comment!=blank e.g.

```
return self.filter(active=True, review_comment!=blank)
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try `review_comment!=""` one time.

Answer (score 2):

Because your `CharField` don't have null setting so default there won't allow null value to be saved. Also Django discourage using null filter on CharField and TextField https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null

For filtering out the blank string you can use [exclude](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#exclude) as chaining query

```
return self.filter(active=True).exclude(review_comment="")
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the answer that you are looking for?

```
return self.filter(active=True, review_comment__isnull=False)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#isnull

Comment: I tried that and it returned an error about null not being among the options.

Comment: I think for this, there should also be `null=True` in models.

Answer (score 0):

I have found through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66754563/django-filter-empty-fields) question that the way to check if a value is blank is to use the exclude

So in my case I did this
`return self.filter(active=True).exclude(review_comment__exact='')`

Comment: don't need to use exact, there no character in a blank string so you don't need to worry about uppercase or extra characters